# solution of another definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, improper-integrals

Does the following integral converge or not?
\begin{align}
&&
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-\varphi)^k \binom{\frac1\varphi+k}{k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\beta x^n e^{-\beta x(k+1)}dx&&
\end{align}
where $e,\beta$ and $\varphi>0$ and $n$ is a positive integer.

Well I just simplified the following integral
[image: png]
and I got the above integral.

Comment: What did you try? Does the domain of integration really start at $-\infty$?

Comment: yes the domain starts at - infinity.

Comment: Then it is quite simple. Why did I ask that? (Note, the integrals must converge first else the sum is undefined.)

Comment: what transformation/change do you suggest to make the integral converge?

Comment: That is a bit funny. Change the term until you get what you want. In that case I propose 0 as the simplest possible term;-). No, seriously, even if the integrals would converge. If the resulting alternating series is convergent but not absolutely convergent you can get any limit value you want by re-ordering the terms. So the question remains: What are admissible modifications of the overall term? What is the origin of the problem?

Comment: Similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718042/analytic-solution-to-definte-integral

Comment: @HarryPeter, would it not be better if we split the limit  [the integral with summation term] into (-inf,0) and (0,inf). In this way the first one will diverge and the second one is Gamma Function.

Comment: @SA-255525 If the lower limit of integration is $-\infty$, then the answer to your question is very simple: since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\beta x^n e^{-\beta x(k+1)}dx$ diverges, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-\varphi)^k \binom{\frac1\varphi+k}{k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\beta x^n e^{-\beta x(k+1)}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-\varphi)^k \binom{\frac1\varphi+k}{k}\infty$ automatically diverges as well. A necessary condition for convergence is that the lower limit of integration be finite.

Comment: @DavidH , what about the integral [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Am4AS.png    Can this be used instead. I mean this was the one that was simplified. Does this also diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
 \beta \frac{x^n e^{-\beta x}}
{\left(1+\varphi e^{-\beta x}\right)^{\frac{1}{\varphi}+1}}\approx \frac{\beta}{\varphi^{1+\varphi^{-1}}} x^n \exp(\frac{\beta}{\varphi}x) \quad\mbox{ for } x\to-\infty, 
$$
so it is clearly convergent at this end, and
$$
 \beta \frac{x^n e^{-\beta x}}
{\left(1+\varphi e^{-\beta x}\right)^{\frac{1}{\varphi}+1}}\approx \beta x^n \exp(- \beta x) \quad\mbox{ for } x\to \infty, 
$$
so it is also clearly convergent at the other end, so it is indeed convergent.

Comment: @ Athanagor Wurlitzer , I am not sure how you got exp((b/phi)x).

Comment: @SA-255525 when $x\ll-1$,  $1$ is negligible compared to $\exp(-\beta x)\phi$ which is very large. So the denominator is $(\phi \exp(-\beta x))^{1+\phi^{-1}}$, which is $\phi^{1+\phi^{-1}}\exp(-\beta/\phi x -\beta x)$. Then simplify with numerator

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\beta x}\left(1+\varphi e^{-bx}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\varphi}-1}~dx$ ,

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\beta x}\left(1+\varphi e^{-bx}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\varphi}-1}~dx$

$=\int_\infty^0x^\frac{\beta}{b}~(1+\varphi x)^{-\frac{1}{\varphi}-1}~d\left(-\dfrac{\ln x}{b}\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{b}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{\beta}{b}-1}(1+\varphi x)^{-\frac{1}{\varphi}-1}~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{b}\int_0^\infty\left(\dfrac{x}{\varphi}\right)^{\frac{\beta}{b}-1}(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{\varphi}-1}~d\left(\dfrac{x}{\varphi}\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{\varphi^\frac{\beta}{b}~b}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{\beta}{b}-1}(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{\varphi}-1}~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{\varphi^\frac{\beta}{b}~b}B\left(\dfrac{\beta}{b},\dfrac{1}{\varphi}-\dfrac{\beta}{b}+1\right)$

$\therefore\int_{-\infty}^\infty\beta x^ne^{-\beta x}\left(1+\varphi e^{-bx}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\varphi}-1}~dx=(-1)^n\beta\dfrac{d^n}{d\beta^n}\left(\dfrac{1}{\varphi^\frac{\beta}{b}~b}B\left(\dfrac{\beta}{b},\dfrac{1}{\varphi}-\dfrac{\beta}{b}+1\right)\right)(b=\beta)$